# How to check if I can log in to server via ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a list of servers:

```
cat list.txt
10.10.10.10 servera
10.11.10.10 serverb
```

How can I check that I can log in via ssh to them or not? I mean by default I should be able to log in via ssh key auth.., so in short, I need a solution that sorts the lines (servers) in the list.txt like this:

- servers that I can log in via ssh key
- servers that prompts for password (of course password is unknown..)
- servers that are unreachable

Comment: with the help of ssh and ping commands u may achieve it

Comment: `ping` isn't really a good indicator. There are a lot of setups that allow `ssh` connections but don't reply to pings.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do that with a combination of the `BatchMode` option and "parsing" the output. (`ssh` always returns 255 if it fails to connect for whatever reason, so you can't use the return code to distinguish between types of failures.)

With `BatchMode` on, no password prompt or other interaction is attempted, so a connect that requires a password will fail. (I also put a `ConnectTimeout` in there which should be adjusted to fit your needs. And picked really bad filenames.)

```
#! /bin/bash

rm good no_auth other
while read ip host ; do
    status=$(ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $ip echo ok 2>&1)
    case $status in
        ok) echo $ip $host >> good ;;
        *"Permission denied"*) echo $ip $host $status >> no_auth ;;
        *) echo $ip $host $status >> other ;;
    esac
done < list.txt
```

You could detect other types of errors (like missing server public key) if you need more detailed classification. If you need the results in a single, sorted file, just `cat` the various output files together as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the various tools that automate running commands on multiple hosts through ssh. For example, with [Mussh](http://mussh.sourceforge.net/):

```
mussh -H hosts.txt -o ConnectTimeout=5 -P -d -c 'echo `hostname` is alive'
```

Massage the output as needed.

Side note: why are you storing IP addresses in `list.txt`? Server names are enough. If the names you want to use aren't the DNS names, use `Host` directives in `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 0):

```
servers that I can log in via ssh key
servers that prompts for password (of course password is unknown..)
```

expect will provide input to your interactive commands.
The ssh client with the -v flag will tell you what auth methods the server accepts.
If you get to the interactive prompt, make it quit.
Do what you wan, you have all you need.

```
servers that are unreachable
```

Same, one command to rule them all, and in the darkness, bind them... Hum.

Answer (score 0):

The mussh command will output only errors so you can just give run it without debug.

```
$ cat list.txt
10.1.2.93       trustme
10.1.2.92       wobudong
10.41.41.41     failhost

$ awk '{print $2}' list.txt | mussh -H - -t 10 -m -c hostname
trustme: trustme
failhost: ssh: Could not resolve hostname failhost: Name or service not known
wobudong: ssh: connect to host wobudong port 22: Connection timed out
```